# is it possible to call an anction inside another action in phalcon?

Tags: transactions, phalcon

I have two forms, one for registering user and another for add a product to user's order list. these two forms are processed in different Controllers (one in user controller and another in order controller).
I need for some specific product have a form which combine these two form in one form, it means that user will register and asks to have that product in his orders list in one step, and then form is submitted via Ajax. is it possible to create an action with this logic:

1. start transaction
2. call create user action
3. call create order action
4. end transaction

or I should duplicate all those codes in third action?
I already put forms in view partials and just have problem for submitting the data.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have these options:

- Do not mix multiple different forms in single request
- Move the complex code from both actions to separate methods and call them from controller actions separately to avoid code duplication
- Use forwarding to other action (will not work as "transaction") http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#forwarding-to-other-actions